# Search 'name.jpeg' files using python taken the name from a .txt and save/copy to other folder

Tags: python, image, copy

I have more than 20000 image files in a single folder. I need to find files that have "special" name and copy them to a different folder using python or something.

The .txt is like this:

```
30601258@N03    11816644924_075c3d8d59_o.jpg    2   (25, 32)    m   175 80  769 768 -75 0   34
30601258@N03    10424595844_1009c687e4_o.jpg    4   (38, 43)    f   1912    905 1224    1224    155 0   64
30601258@N03    10190308156_5c748ab2da_o.jpg    2   (25, 32)    m   1013    1039    453 452 -75 0   59
```

So second column is the name of the image, and i want to copy it only if the 5th column is an 'm'

I think i need to read all the .txt line by line and if i found an 'm' in the 5 column of the line, i need to find the second column name in the folder and copy the image to other folder.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that is what you need to do. How about trying to put that into code and see how far you get? You will need to read about `open()`, `for` loops, `split()`, and one of the file copy functions from the `shutil` module.

Comment: hi, @mhawke i don't know how to use the shutil library or where i need to put the script, btw thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Ok i need to change because images not are in a simple directory, each image have their own directory that is the first column of the txt.

i make this:

```
import shutil

part = 'landmark_aligned_face.'


def main():
    f = file("0.txt","r")
    for lines in f:
        line = lines.split('\t')
        if line[4] == 'm':
            directory = line[0]
            name = line[2] + '.'
            image = part + name + line[1]
            print image


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

whit this if there are an 'm' i have the name image in 'image' and the directory in 'directory'
How can i use the 'shutil' library? And where i need to put the script to find the directorys?

Thanks